# can we use rowspan and colspan in displaytag?

Tags: html, css, jsp, datagrid, displaytag

I have to create a table, whose structure is like this

```
|--------------------------------|  
|col1|col2|      col3       |col4|  
|    |    | col3.1 | col3.2 |    |  
|----|----|--------|--------|----|  
|----|----|--------|--------|----|
```

Is it possible to create such a datagrid using display tag?

Comment: `Displaytag:` http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/

Comment: What the heck, i used the `displaytag` tag and it is david who removed that tag from the question. Anyways does it make any sense `Maybe you should ask someone who works on display tag?`  In SO there are lots of question related to `Displaytag`. How could i know that the person who will try to answer don't even know displaytag and still want to answer.

Comment: There updated your question to have the correct tagging, like you originally had it, other than that good luck, never heard of this product.

Comment: If you don't know what X is but you're interested to know about, just Google X and move along. This kind of comments only clutters and distracts the whole question (sigh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the decorator examples (http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_decorators.html), that is your best bet.

Another way to do it is to add the content of the cell manually, like so:

```
<display:column titleKey="something" media="html">

       <c:out_of_property_here>

</display:column>
```

If I remember correctly, if my table was defined like:

```
<display:table name="test" requestURI="some_uri"
    defaultsort="0" id="test" export="true" excludedParams="*" >
```

you would access the current element using `test`, so if the object you are displaying has a property `id` with a getter `getId`, you would access the current object in the list by writing `test.id`.

But I would try using a decorator first (you can add decorators per-column iirc), the second option is very messy.

Comment: at present i am using the later soltion, [ using c:out inside display:column ], but i guess i should check out that decorator too.

Comment: what it <c:out_of_property_here>