# How to group column headers using the Display tag Java library?

Tags: java, displaytag

I am using the [Display tag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) Java library in my web application. I need to group some column headers ("General" and "Office Info") as shown in the following example.

[image]

Comment: @Remy It is a third party library used in java web aplications for listing and pagination purposes.  Please refer http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

Comment: No answers as yet? Is it possible to do it at all or shall I just forget about doing it?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831631/can-we-use-rowspan-and-colspan-in-displaytag

Comment: get the sourcecode of displaytag and edit it. i havent done the exact same thing you are trying to achieve but I have done subtotalling and totallings of the numeric column data and like into a separate cell on the last row.
For that I extended the table and added one or two methods of my own.

Comment: look at this example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GroupableGroupHeaderExample.htm

Comment: @johntotetwoo The question is about using the DisplayTag 3rd party plug-in for Web applications. your Swing answer is not relevant.

Comment: How this can be implemented in Core Java, Swing programming.. I too have same situation to work on with an requirement..

Answer (score 3):

Ashish, I tried to clarify your question and have hopefully got it right.

If you check the HTML source generated by DisplayTag it puts the column headings into a `<thead>` tag like this

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="dtsortable">
            <a href="...">Firstname</a>
        </th>
        <th class="dtsortable">
            <a href="...">Lastname</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
...
```

So what you want to achieve is inserting a new row into the  for your groupings. I would suggest that the easiest way to achieve this is not to mess with DisplayTag code and use JQuery to manipulate the DOM to do this.

**Using JQuery**

To get this HTML code...

```
<table id="display-tag "cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
            heading
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="dtsortable">
            <a href="...">Firstname</a>
        </th>
        <th class="dtsortable">
            <a href="...">Lastname</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You can use this JQuery code...

```
$('#display-tag > thead').prepend('<tr><th colspan="2">heading</th></tr>');
```

You can [see this in action with this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uPB3A/2/)

Answer (score -3):

you will do like this

Roles
                             CASBAdmin
                             TEUser
                              PubUser
                               PWUser
                                MedUser
                                 CommonUser
                             " sortable="true">